# Convert string to dict

Tags: python, json

I am reading multiple `json_file` and storing them in `json_text` like this:

```
json_text = json_file.read()
```

When I `print` `json_text` I get the following information:

```
{
  "speech": {
    "text": "<p>Lords</p><p>We are all in the same boat</p><p>It is time for us to help</p>",
    "id": null,
    "doc_id": null,
    "fave": "N",
    "system": "2015-09-24 13:00:17"
 }
}
<type 'str'>
```

I was assuming I would get this as a dict by using `json.loads()` but that doesn't work:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Apparently `loads()` doesn't identify `json_text` as JSON, even though it is a valid JSON according to [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) So I thought I'd use `dump()` and then `loads()`:

```
json_dumps = json.dumps(json_text)
json_loads = json.loads(json_dumps)
print json_loads, type(json_loads)
```

Gives:

```
{
  "speech": {
    "text": "<p>Lords</p><p>We are all in the same boat</p><p>It is time for us to help</p>",
    "id": null,
    "doc_id": null,
    "fave": "N",
    "system": "2015-09-24 13:00:17"
 }
}
<type 'unicode'>
```

I've also tried using `ast` and `literal_eval()` on `json_text` but then I get:

> ValueError: malformed string

So. The scenario is that I have multiple json-files in a folder. I want to load these files and take specific keys and store them in a `pandas` `DataFrame`. I've tried `pd.read_json()` but it just tells me that there is something wrong with my `json`.

This is my code:

```
path_to_json = 'folder/'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
         json.load(json_file)
```

Gives `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` and therefor I've tried using `json_file.read()` et.c.

Comment: Can you exactly show how you do `json.loads()`?

Comment: `json_text` in you code snippet is not a string. `json.loads()` takes a string and converts it to  JSON. you are already getting a JSON as `json_text`. I am not sure what your issue is. can you explain?

Comment: @KrishnaKishoreAndhavarapu I want `<type 'dict'>` so that I can access keys by `data['speech']['text']` et.c.

Comment: @user3471881 to read a json file you should use the json.load(filename) function, not the json.loads(string).

Comment: Have you checked when it fails? Aka is the content of the file really the JSON you posted at the top?

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd No [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) needs a file like object.

Comment: I know @HeadhunterXamd - check the code. I use `json.load` on a file object. it get's messy because I've tried different ways. Yes, the content of the file is really the JSON posted. At least it's the content I get when I do `json_file.read()`

Comment: what is `json_file` in your code? 
You should do something like `fd = open('file.json', 'r')
json_str = fd.read()
dict = json.loads(json_str)`

Comment: Okay can you make sure that it is encoded as ASCII (or UTF-8)? Because in Python 2 [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.loads) requires an encoding if it is not ASCII/UTF-8. If it is not UTF8 compatible (e.g. UTF-16) you get a `ValueError`: `json.loads(u'{"id": null}'.encode("utf16"))`

Comment: @xZise I know, what I meant was to let json.load() read  the file instead of reading it with a file reader and then trying to load it.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd Well the example code at the bottom of the OP is using `json.load`. And it is still not `json.load(filename)`.

Comment: @xZise I saw that after the comment, my bad :X
What is the file encoding?

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd I don't think we can actually know this. At least if I print a UTF-16 string without BOM it looks fine to me. This is why I suggested in my answer to output the `repr` of that string to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments it will also cause a `ValueError` if the encoding is not ASCII based. For example the following `json.loads` fails:

```
>>> json.loads(u'{"id": null}'.encode("utf16"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

One way you could look at the encoding is to `print(repr(json_text))` which could show additional bytes (like in UTF-16):

```
>>> print(repr(u'{"id": null}'.encode("utf16")))
'\xff\xfe{\x00"\x00i\x00d\x00"\x00:\x00 \x00n\x00u\x00l\x00l\x00}\x00'
```

The `json.load` and `json.loads` both support in Python 2 an encoding parameter. But that only applies to ASCII based encodings, so for UTF-16 you get the same `ValueError`:

```
>>> json.loads(u'{"id": null}'.encode("utf16"), encoding="utf16")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

If that is still the case (and you are sure that the issue it being encoded incorrectly) you can either decode the string manually:

```
json_text = json_text.decode("utf16")
```

Or you can load the file using `codecs.open`:

```
with codecs.open(json_file_name, "r", encoding="utf16") as f:
    print(json.load(f))
    # or
    # json_text = f.read()
```

(Note that I'm using UTF-16 here, but this might not be in the case for you)

And looking from your JSON text the characters itself are all ASCII characters, so any ASCII based encoding (e.g. latin-1) would still work without any decoding because there is no difference between that JSON content encoded in ASCII, UTF8 or latin-1.

As a side note you dumped the text and loaded it, and got a `unicode` object back. In theory (if my answer is correct) you should be able to actually load `json_loads` (aka `json.loads(json_loads)`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your error. I'm able to run as expected with this code:

```
import json

strdata = """
{
    "speech": {
        "text": "<p>Lords</p><p>We are all in the same boat</p><p>It is time for us to help</p>",
        "id": null,
        "doc_id": null,
        "fave": "N",
        "system": "2015-09-24 13:00:17"
    }
}
"""

data = json.loads(strdata)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a question of encoding, maybe already by reading from file. You should use the appropriate encoding as parameter in json.loads.